# Replace part of a string using regex in VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net

In my application, when the user enters, for example, a parameters named : DateSTA (STA stands for START) an other parameters is automaticaly added with the name "DateEND".

So, in my application, I check if the parameter entred ends with "STA" so I launch the code for creating the other parameters automaticaly.

```
If namePara.EndsWith("STA") Then
Dim nameEnd as string = Regex.Replace(namePara, "******", "END", RegexOptions.None)
```

To do it, I need a regex (the ***** in the code) that searches the "STA" in a string and replace it with "END"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
Dim nameEnd as String = namePara.Remove(namePara.Length - 3) & "END"
```

But if you must use Regex:

```
Dim nameEnd as String = Regex.Replace(namePara, "STA$", "END")
```